# Entity Framework stops loading related entities after a while

Tags: c#, entity-framework, orm

It seems that after 5-40 hours of using the same Entity Framework context, entities stop loading related objects. (ex: `Character.Items` is null). All entities loaded prior to this issue are fine, and they load correctly - it occurs on entities loaded from the database instead of cache.

I am using Entity Framework in a game server project where the context has to remain active for the whole duration (otherwise the context loses track of objects). The server is run in a single thread, and all database related functions (such as loading character data, items, relations, etc) are done in a separate DB Thread ( ex: `Game.DbExecute(() => { ... })` ). Any time an entity with relations is loaded, all related data is loaded in the same DB thread, and cached either in a list or dictionary for later use by the game thread. On average we start out with 5,000 entities, and 50,000 non-tracked entities (mostly data such as skill info, monster info, item info, etc). However during runtime, it's entirely possible we add/use 50,000 - 100,000 or more entities until we do a maintenance.

The only time the DB thread is not used when accessing entities is when an entity value is set directly - ex: `Character.Name = "..."`;

Could this be the source of my problem, or does the issue lay somewhere else? Has anyone else experienced this issue?

Comment: I have never experienced this, but the contexts aren't built for the purpose you are describing. I take it debug information is hard to come by since it takes a couple of hours till it happens?

Comment: Yes, I'm usually unable to catch it because it's so random - However, I was able to catch it once, but there were no errors thrown, it simply stopped loading. I'm going to try adding the EF source to the project and step through the entire load process.

Comment: Did you find anything?

Comment: The error hasn't occurred in over 24 hours despite more testing.